# In middleman how do I add head tags from a child-layout?

Tags: middleman

In middleman I'm wondering how to add head tags to my base layout from a sub layout.

I have a layout.erb and a blog-layout.erb.

I approached the problem in Jekyll by putting the additional items in the YAML frontmatter of the layout and I like that approach.

I've been trying to recreate it in Middleman, but it hasn't been working.

I have my blog-layout.erb like this:

```
---
head:
 - -<%= feed_tag :atom, "/blog/feed.xml", title: "Atom Feed" %>'
---

<% wrap_layout :layout do %>
<div id="main" role="main">
  <%= yield %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

then in my layout.erb I want to do this:

```
<% current_page.data.head.each do |headItem| %>
    < % = headItem %>
< % end %>
```

I tried accessing the layout's frontmatter from config.rb, but I didn't get that to work either.

Here was one of my attempts:

```
with_layout :bloglayout do
   page "/blog/*", :headers => config[:bloglayout].head
end
```

I couldn't figure out where in global the layouts are stored and how to access them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Padrino's [application helper](http://padrinorb.com/guides/application-helpers/) `content_for`elegantly handles adding head tags from a wrapped layout.

My layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" >
    <%= yield_content :head %>
```

My bloglayout:

```
<% wrap_layout :layout do %>

    <%= yield %>

    <% content_for :head do %>
      <%= feed_tag :atom, "/blog/feed.xml", :title => "Atom Feed tag" %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

My config.rb

```
activate :blog do |blog|
  blog.layout = "bloglayout"
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't figure out yet how to do it through child layout frontmatter.

What I did was created a datafile: blogmetaheaders.yml

```
headers: >
 <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Atom Feed" href="/blog/feed.xml" />
```

Then in my layout.rb I have this code to inject headers:

```
<% if current_page.path.start_with? 'blog'
        data.blogmetaheaders.each do |headerItem, headerValue | %>
        <%= headerValue %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
```